# Can DNN Skins have content panes with a blank element instead of a div?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, skinning

All example skins I've seen use `<div id="SomethingSomethingPane" runat="server"></div>`.  Is it possible to use something other than a div?  Ideally I'd like to use something that doesn't require additional HTML mark up, such as an `<asp:Literal>` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have four methods at your disposal for creating Panes in a DNN Skin, as of DNN 5**

**TD**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="ContentPane" runat="server"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**DIV**

```
<div id="ContentPane" runat="server" />
```

**SPAN**

```
<span id="ContentPane" runat="server" />
```

**P**

```
<p id="ContentPane" runat="server" />
```

If you need to remove the tag altogether, have some jquery run upon page load that [strips that tag](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) (select by ID), although an empty span is pretty harmless in most cases.

**References**

- [Page 468 of this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470438703) - `div`, `span`, `td`
- [DNN Source](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64458#986789) - `p`, search for "//load the skin panes"

Comment: Hi ScottS, is there a reference for this sort of thing? I'd like to include it in my answer if I can locate one. Thanks!

Comment: I referenced my notes from reviewing the source for an internal presentation I did on the DNN architecture.  You can see the list of acceptable elements in the Skin.cs file, LoadPanes method.  http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64458#986789 around line 330 at present

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use something other than a `div` such as a `span`.